# WSUS "Feature pack" and "Update rollback" exist for one KB, any difference

Tags: wsus

all

I found in WSUS, there are two updates as per below for KB2977218(Silverlight5.1.30514.0).

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTHxT.png]

I found WSUS description in below  but can not catch if there is any difference in module.

> Feature packs:    New product functionality usually included in the next full product release.
>
> Update rollups:   Cumulative set of hotfixes, security updates, critical updates, and updates packaged together for easy deployment.

can anyone help me,

- Do I need to install both of update ( featured pack  and rollup )?
- If both are same, what is difference between those two items in single KB2977218

Regards, Maka

Answer (score 1):

From the [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2977218):

> this update will be offered as **"Update for Microsoft Silverlight (KB2977218)."** If a computer does not have Silverlight installed, this update will be offered as **"Microsoft Silverlight (KB2977218)."**

The latter is categorized as a feature pack because installing it for the first time adds additional functionality to clients. It's not an *update*.